# Не могу посмотреть, что происходит в коде через отладчик

Tags: c#

Нажимаю F11 вот что выбивает. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пишу дискорд бота если что

Comment: Что тут не так?

Comment: я хочу посмотреть как мой проект компилится, а я не могу.

Comment: Что конкретно вы ожидаете увидеть? Процесс сборки смотрите во вкладке output. На скрине Вы показываете главный метод и что в нем точка останова сработала - так и должно быть по идее. Потому не понятно, что не так у вас?

Comment: Это юнит тест проект, его не прлучится по f11 отлаживать. В окне test explorer есть кнопки для отладки.